# How can I create linting errors (in typescript) if no jsdoc for public functions or variables is provided?

Tags: eslint, public, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

I want to make sure that all of my public variables and methods in my code are documented.

I have tried to use eslint-plugin-jsdoc and have activated all of the recommended rules. Additionally, I added the following rule to raise errors when there is no documentation for public methods:

```
"jsdoc/require-jsdoc": [
   "error",
      {
          "publicOnly": true,
      }
   ],
```

However, "publicOnly" in this case does not refer to **public** methods/variables but to those that are **export**ed from the module. Is there a way (besides creating a custom plugin) to achieve the same behavior for public methods/variables?

Comment: What does "I have activated all of the recommended rules" mean? Because if you follow the example shown in [options](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-jsdoc#options) you will get the behavior that you describe, so if you *aren't* seeing that behavior then it's likely that you have not enabled the options as described.

Comment: @anothermh Oh god, you are right! I didn't see that most of the fields in the "require" options are set to **false** by default. Thanks a lot, this fixed my problem :)